# Converting dummy variable into a variable that shows in which period an individual is taken out

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have a dataset in Excel where measurements (M) have been taken from different individuals (ID) in several time periods (T) (M1 equal a measurement taken in period 1, M2 a measurement taken in period 2 etc.).

Some individuals are removed during the time of the experiment. This is represented by a dummy variable that indicates whether an individual is removed in a certain period or not (Rd).
Since individuals dont have measurements taken after they have been removed, the situation looks like this in a simplified version.

ID;T;M;Rd
1;1;M1;0
2;1;M1;0
3;1;M1;1
1;2;M2;0
2;2;M2;1
1;3;M3;0

What I need, is to have a variable that tells me directly in which period the individual was removed from the experiment ( unlike the dummy variable which just tell me whether a tree is removed in a certain period or not).

Furthermore, what was not clear from my first attempt of writing this question is that I need to have the information about in which time period that an individual is removed next to the measurement in time period 1 (the baseline measurement).

Thus, what I want to achieve is a situation as below where the variable R has been created to represent in which period the measurement is taken out.

ID;T;M1;R
1;1;M1;0
2;1;M1;2
3;1;M1;1

Where R= 1 show that individual 3 is removed in period 1 and R=2 show that individual 2 is removed in period 2, while R=0 show that individual 1 is not taken out. And all this information is next to M1.

The reason why I need this data setup is because I need to model forward the development of these individuals (from the baseline measurement, M1) and compare this modelled development to the actual development from the experiment.

Thus, to model this development as accurate as possible, I need the first measurement (the baseline measurement) and next to this baseline measurement, the information about when the individual is taken out.

Thus, I cannot simply filter the data, since the majority of the information concerning when an individual is removed is belonging to measurements taken in other periods.

Is there any function in Excel that can do this for me (converting from Rd to R)?

Thank you very much for your help! Sorry that everything was not clear from the beginning.

Kind regards

Ditlev

Comment: Very easy way: Just filter the Rd column to only show rows where Rd is set to 1. If you need results returned in a different location on the spreadsheet, you could probably use the vlookup function to find instances of #1 in Rd, then return the ID.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have now updated the question to highlight why filtering is not an option to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, Ditlev.

To display the results in the first rows, an INDIRECT() reference is needed.  Also, for the longest lasting individual to have a result of 0, an IF function checks whether the result is the last row of the data, and sets it to 0 if so.

This formula will do the job.

=IF(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($2:$7)*(A$2:A$7=A2)))=ROWS($2:$7)+1,

0,INDIRECT("B"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($2:$7)*(A$2:A$7=A2)))))

This assumes your data table starts in A1. The formula goes in D2 and is filled down only to the end of the first trial.  Of course you should change the $2:$7 ranges to refer to your entire data table. Best of luck.

The results are shown below.

[image]

Comment: Question for all:  Is there any simple way to paste a table from Excel into an answer, while retaining some semblance of formatting?  It seems like pasting a picture is the only viable solution.  And that involves a lot of effort that *shouldn't* be necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. It was clear to me that I had not explained the situation well enough. I have now updated the question to especially highlight that I need to have the information about when an individual is removed next to the measurement from the first time period (M1).

Comment: Thank you @Bandersnatch. This seems to have solved my problem. However, I have one strange observation. When I typed in you formulae just like you did, then I had no problem. But when I copy the formulae, it seems like the IF function fails to return 0 for individuals that are not removed at all during the time of the experiment. Can you replicate failure this by copying and pasting your table?

Comment: I am having some difficulties inserting the table. But basically I get the exact same result when I copy it apart from that the individual that is never removed have a R value of 3 (and not 0 as it originally had).

Comment: I imagine that has something to do with the fact that I split the formula over two lines in the answer.  Try copying and pasting the two parts separately.  Or use this:  
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($2:$7)*(A$2:A$7=A2)))=ROWS($2:$7)+1,0,INDIRECT("B"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW($2:$7)*(A$2:A$7=A2)))))

Comment: @Ditlev I tried to paste the equation and got several errors. Some of the characters were not recognized - Excel complained about the 0 in the IF test for example. I tried pasting it into a text app and converting to plain text.  There were then spaces that had to be removed.  I never did get it to work.  If you get the right behavior by typing the equation, can you just run with that?  :-)

Comment: I finally got it to work by doing several things: 1) convert to plain text. 2) remove spaces. 3) delete and retype the 0 in IF test. 4) retype " " around B. 5) Copy the first section of SUMPRODUCT...A2 and paste it over the second one.  That did it.  I've had similar problems pasting from Word into Excel. "Curly quotes" e.g. are a different character that what our keyboards type.  Good luck with this.  If you found my answer and comments helpful, please award points as shown [here](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: thank you @Bandersnatch, I have now accepted your answer, and I hope that you have gotten the vote up as well, i get the message that when I have less than 15 in reputation it is not shown in public but I hope that you got it. Let me know if there is something else I can do to give you credit, you have been extremely helpful!